# Connect certain pixels in an image through edges Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a martrix A representing a 640x480 image and another matrix index_matrix which contains some indices as shown:

```
[1  639;
212 210;
213 208;
214 209;
215 211;
216 210;
217 211];
```

The first col is corresponds to the row index in martix A and the second col corresponds to the col index in matrix A, so each row in the index_matrix represents a the index of a pixel in martix A, e.g the first row in the above example of index_matrix represents the index of the pixel located in row_1 col_639. So I want to connect only the points of martix A found in the index_matrix, where each point of those points will be connected to the nearest two other points in the index_matrix. This is like building a tree or a graph between these points. Such that the edges of this graph connecting two points should be drawn on pixels having values greater than zero, so if a pixel of value equal to zero was in the edge path, this edge connecting the two points will not be constructed and the two points will not be connected.
So as shown in this [image: fig] if pixels A, B and C's indices where in the index_matrix and A and B will be connected, B and C will be connected, while A and C will not be connected because when constructing the path of the edge will path through a zero valued pixel "circled". So I'm asking if anyone could please advise how can I do this?

Comment: Do you want the red line in your example "interrupted" by the zero pixel, or not drawn at all?

Comment: @Floris just to clarify that these values are the pixels values. I'm not sure what do you mean by "interrupted" but yes if during constructing the edge path a zero pixel is found this edge will not be drawn

Comment: @Floris I'm wondering if you have any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) command to draw a line between two points on your image. What you can do is store the original image (say, `I`) and keep drawing on another image (say, `C`).

Suppose we start at the second point `(212,210)`. Then we need two lines, `(212,210) - (1,639)` and `(212,210) - (213,208)`. Let's look at the first line.

You can either compute the discrete points on the line segment between the two points or use the `plot` function to draw it on a blank image say `M = zeros(size(I));`. Now, `M` (for mask) will only have white pixels where the line would be drawn.

You can then make it a logical mask (`M == 255`) and check if there are any zeros in the original image `I` which correspond to `true` pixels in `M`.

**UPDATE:** Since the method of using a mask every time is a bit lame, and using the equation of a line and discretizing is not the best way to draw a line, I would recommend using the [`bresenham`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28190-bresenham-optimized-for-matlab/content/bresenham.m) function to obtain a list of points on the line segment. You can easily check the values and decide to keep the line or not without messing with masks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually I want to draw a line not only between the one before and one after, but also with every other point, e.g in my example I'll try to draw a line between (1,639) and all the other 6 pixels. Is it possible to try to a script to do this as I'm not very familiar with plotting, I'd very thankful! Many Thanks

Comment: Yes, you just need to use a fresh mask every time to check the points along the lines. I would recommend looking at my updated answer which uses `bresenham`. Note that it needs to be downloaded from MATLAB central.